# Using data from a stored procedure in Sql Server to fill an Access continuous form

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, continuous-forms

I'm trying to fill a **continuous form** in **access 2013** using data from a **stored procedure** in **ms sql server 2014**. The database connection works, I can use other access forms to add data to the ms sql server database. So that's not the problem.
Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spArtikelen AS
BEGIN
SELECT a.artikelnr, omschrijving, v.voorraad, p.prijs, a.leverancier
FROM artikel AS a, artikelprijs AS p, artikelvoorraad AS v
WHERE a.artikelnr = p.artikelnr 
AND a.artikelnr = v.artikelnr 
AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN p.begindatum AND p.einddatum
END
```

And here's my vba code (I put the vba code on the LOAD event of the form):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = DbConn.Execute("EXEC spArtikelen")
        Do Until rs.EOF
            Me.txtArtikelnr.Value = rs!artikelnr
            Me.txtOmschrijving.Value = rs!omschrijving
            Me.txtVoorraad.Value = rs!voorraad
            Me.txtPrijs.Value = rs!prijs
            Me.txtLeverancier.Value = rs!leverancier
            Debug.Print rs!artikelnr, rs!omschrijving, rs!voorraad, rs!prijs, rs!leverancier
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
End Sub!
```

[the continuous form..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGXSZ.png)

How do I fix this? I've been trying to get it work all day.. without success..
Every time I run the form, I only get one record, and I can't click through the records.!

[Here's the data from the stored procedure I'm trying to put into the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn9gJ.png)
[Possible solution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uJyu.png)

Comment: Another option might be to create a pass-through query in Access to run the stored procedure, then just bind the form to the pass-through query. (The recordset will still be read-only, however.)

Comment: @GordThompson I thought your suggestion should be more prominent, so added it to my answer.  I'll gladly remove it if you prefer to submit it as a separate answer.  Regards.

Comment: @HansUp No worries, your answer looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your recordset with *adUseClient* for its `CursorLocation` property.  Then set the form's `Recordset` property to your ADO recordset.

```vb
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "EXEC spArtikelen", DbConn
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

Then with *artikelnr* for `txtArtikelnr.ControlSource`, *omschrijving* for `txtOmschrijving.ControlSource`, and so forth the form should load with the recordset rows as you wish.

Note the data displayed within the form will be read-only.  Hopefully that is not an unwelcome surprise.

Also, I suggested this approach because you already had a suitable ADO recordset.  However, I think Gord's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149105/using-data-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-to-fill-an-access-continuous-fo#comment46525167_29149105) to use a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303968) as your form's `RecordSource` is simpler.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for your reply! Though, I'm unfamiliar with the property ControlSource. Should it be something like this?
(I'll edit the post with an image) Called "Possible Solution".

Comment: There is not a simple direct way to edit data returned from that stored procedure.  You could create and execute `UPDATE` statements for each of the 3 tables involved in the stored procedure.  If you want to go that route, please tackle it as a new question.